# MongoDB: get sum by year/month with nested values

Tags: mongodb, sum, aggregate, nested-object

I'm trying to sum (spending by month/year) of a collection with nested amounts - with no luck.

This is the collection (extract):

```
[
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5faaf88d0657287993e541a5"),
    "segment" : {
        "l1" : "Segment A",
        "l2" : "001"
    },
    "invoiceNo" : "2020.10283940",
    "invoicePos" : 3,
    "date" : ISODate("2019-09-06T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "amount" : {
        "document" : {
            "amount" : NumberDecimal("125.000000000000"),
            "currCode" : "USD"
        },
        "local" : {
            "amount" : NumberDecimal("123.800000000000"),
            "currCode" : "CHF"
        },
        "global" : {
            "amount" : NumberDecimal("123.800000000000"),
            "currCode" : "CHF"
        }
    }
},
...
]
```

I would like to sum up the aggregated invoice volume per month in "global" currency.

I tried this query on MongoDB:

```
db.invoices.aggregate( 
       {$project : { 
              month : {$month : "$date"}, 
              year : {$year :  "$date"},
              amount : 1
          }},
        {$unwind: '$amount'}, 
        {$group : { 
                _id : {month : "$month" ,year : "$year" },  
              total : {$sum : "$amount.global.amount"} 
        }})
```

I am getting as result this:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5faaf88d0657287993e541a5"),
    "amount" : {
        "document" : {
            "amount" : NumberDecimal("125.000000000000"),
            "currCode" : "USD"
        },
        "local" : {
            "amount" : NumberDecimal("123.800000000000"),
            "currCode" : "CHF"
        },
        "global" : {
            "amount" : NumberDecimal("123.800000000000"),
            "currCode" : "CHF"
        }
    },
    "month" : 9,
    "year" : 2019
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5faaf88d0657287993e541ac"),
    "amount" : {
        "document" : {
            "amount" : NumberDecimal("105.560000000000"),
            "currCode" : "CHF"
        },
        "local" : {
            "amount" : NumberDecimal("105.560000000000"),
            "currCode" : "CHF"
        },
        "global" : {
            "amount" : NumberDecimal("105.560000000000"),
            "currCode" : "CHF"
        }
    },
    "month" : 11,
    "year" : 2020
}
```

This however does not sum up all invoices per month, but looks like single invoice lines - no aggregation.

I would like to get a result like this:

```
[
  {
    "month": 11,
    "year": 2020,
    "amount" : NumberDecimal("99999.99") 
  },
  {
    "month": 10,
    "year": 2020,
    "amount" : NumberDecimal("99999.99") 
  },
  {
    "month": 9,
    "year": 2020,
    "amount" : NumberDecimal("99999.99") 
  }
]
```

What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 1):

Would this be helpful?

```
db.invoices.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        month: {
          $month: "$date"
        },
        year: {
          $year: "$date"
        }
      },
      total: {
        $sum: "$amount.global.amount"
      }
    }
  },
  {$sort:{"_id.year":-1, "_id.month":-1}}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yvSLMkIPHWU)

If you need any extra explanation let me know, but the code is pretty short and self-explanatory.

Comment: Excellent, that works! 
With 500k+ records however, this method does not accomplish the task within 30 secs. Is there another way to perform the query?

Comment: You can try {$limit:<number>} as a stage after $sort then after it founds the best documents, it stops looking for more @Herdy

Answer (score 0):

In principle your aggregation pipeline is fine, there a few mistakes:

- An aggregation pipeline expects an **array**
- `$unwind` is useless, because `$amount` is not an array. One element in -> one document out
- You can use date function directly

So, short and simple:

```
db.invoices.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { month: { $month: "$date" }, year: { $year: "$date" } },
      total: { $sum: "$amount.global.amount" }
    }
  }
])
```